# Using colour gradient in scatter3D()

Tags: r

I am trying to add a colour gradient to a scatter3D() plot. The current code I have been using is:

```
    k <- 5    # KNN parameter

    KNN_Outlier <- kNNdist(x=PB_Predictors, k = k)[,k]    # KNN distance 
    (outlier score) computation

    scatter3D(Stamps$V1, Stamps$V2, Stamps$V3, 
      type = "p", pch = 19, cex = 0.4,    # type of mark, shape of mark, 
    size of mark
              col = c("red", "blue"),
              colvar = KNN_Outlier,
              main = "Stamps data",
              xlab = "V1",
              ylab = "V2",
              zlab = "V3")
```

The end result plots the graph I am after, but with just two sold colours of red and blue, rather than a gradient.

What do I need to add to change the colours to a gradient rather than solid red and blue?

Comment: This is not reproducible and you do not specify which package the `scatter3D` function comes from.

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example? You can either provide (a sample of) your data, or try to recreate a minimal example of your issue using a dataset available in base R, such as `mtcars`.